# Module compiled in Swift 4.1 cannot be imported in Swift 4.0.3

Tags: swift, xcode

I tried to clone a project from Github onto Swift and received this error. I am very new to Swift and coding so it would be extremely helpful if you could be as simple as possible when explaining to me how to solve this problem. Thank you

Comment: If the project has cocoapods integrated, you'll need to `install cocoapods`, clear your project and build again

Answer (score 0):

Hi You need to make an update to be able to import the project